# Applescript results to txt file

Tags: applescript, itunes-sdk

I'm trying to write an apple script that gets the unwatched TVShows and puts the filename (preferably without the full path, just "whatever.m4v") in a text file.

Here is the code I have:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set watchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is false and played count > 0
    set unwatchedEpisodes to tracks of playlist "TV Shows" whose unplayed is true
    if (count unwatchedEpisodes) > 0 then
        set trackNames to {}
        repeat with anEpisode in unwatchedEpisodes
            set end of trackNames to ((name of anEpisode) as text) & " of show " & show of anEpisode & " Filename: " & location of anEpisode
        end repeat

        set {TID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}

        set unwatchedTVShows to trackNames as text
        do shell script "echo " & unwatchedTVShows & " > /Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi/unwatchedTVShows.txt"

        #display dialog trackNames as text

        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID
    end if
end tell
```

I get the following error:

```
error "iTunes got an error: sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file" number 2
```

If I replace the "unwatchedTVShows" varible in the do shell statement like this:

```
do shell script "echo " & "test" & " > /Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi/unwatchedTVShows.txt"
```

it works as I expect (I have a filename called "unwatchedTVShows.txt" and it contains the word "test".  I can use the "Display dialog trackNames as text" line that I currently have commented and it works fine.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of shows contains quotes and spaces. Just escape the entire list with `quoted form of`:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of unwatchedTVShows & " > /Volumes/Data/Media/Kodi/unwatchedTVShows.txt"
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!!